# WCF SOAP dynamic ContentType handling from client

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, .net-4.0, content-type

I have WCF SOAP service. One of operation return dynamic ContentType response. I tried to change request ContentType, add headers but no luck, ended into the same error.

See below:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = MimeType(document.Front.FileName);

e.g. MimeType
{".PDF", "application/pdf" },
{".JPG", "image/jpeg"},
{".PNG", "image/png"},
```

Server config:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicSecureBinding_IManager" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">              
      <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
  </binding>
</binding>
```

Client config:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_DataService.IDataService"
         allowCookies="false"
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         messageEncoding="Text"
         textEncoding="utf-8"
         transferMode="Buffered"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
        realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

As server and client configurations are very similar and are working for other SOAP APIs. But for an above-mentioned piece of code, it gives me an error.

> Error:
>   The content type application/pdf of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000JVBERi0x...

**How I can invoke that operation to support dynamic content type?**

**NOTE:**
I can not change server-side code.